Why isn’t the session deleted when logging out from the Spring Authorization Server?
I’m using Spring Authorization Server with Keycloak for social login, and it’s set up as OIDC (OpenID Connect). My issue is with the logout endpoint. I haven’t customized any endpoints, just the ID and access tokens.
I follow:

doc

this question

YouTube tutorial


but nothing work with me.
I have four main entities involved:

Client: A React web app registered as a confidential OIDC client on the Spring Authorization Server.
Resource Server: A Spring Boot application with secure REST endpoints that uses the Spring Authorization Server as its identity provider.
Keycloak: Acts as the social login provider.
Spring Authorization Server: the authorization server for the React/resource server and a confidential client in Keycloak for authentication.

I am using Maven with the following versions in my `pom.xml`:

spring boot 3.3.3

Spring Authorization Server: 1.3.2

OAuth2 Client (Spring Security): 6.3.3


When I test the logout endpoint (/connect/logout) in Postman, it redirects to the login page without logging out. The access token still works with the resource server(I expected a 403 error).
Also when using logout In frontend, it takes me back to the home page without clearing the user session or showing the login page.
I've tried to debug this, and I find SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication(); returns null, and the principal is ANONYMOUS_AUTHENTICATION.
What am I missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated!
My configs as follow:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableJdbcHttpSession
public class AuthorizationServerConfig {

    @Bean
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    public SecurityFilterChain authorizationSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
        http.getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class)
                .oidc(Customizer.withDefaults());    // Enable OpenID Connect 1.0

        http
                .sessionManagement(sessionManagement ->
                        sessionManagement
                                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
                                .maximumSessions(1)
                                .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry())
                )
                .exceptionHandling((exceptions) -> exceptions
                        .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(
                                new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/oauth2/authorization/keycloak"),
                                new MediaTypeRequestMatcher(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
                        )
                )
                .oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2) -> oauth2.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()));
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(2)
    public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http, ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository)
            throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.ignoringRequestMatchers(
                        "/userinfo",
                        "/oauth2/token",
                        "/oauth2/jwks"
                ))
                .oauth2Login(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .logout(logoutConfigurer -> logoutConfigurer
                        .logoutUrl("/connect/logout")
                        .clearAuthentication(true)
                        .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                        .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                        .logoutSuccessHandler(oidcLogoutSuccessHandler(clientRegistrationRepository)));
        return http.build();
    }


    @Bean
    public JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource() {
        KeyPair keyPair = generateRsaKey();
        RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();
        RSAPrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyPair.getPrivate();
        RSAKey rsaKey = new RSAKey.Builder(publicKey)
                .privateKey(privateKey)
                .keyID("2978b2d6-1205-40b5-98df-7e6fbf5f10d0")
//                .algorithm(com.nimbusds.jose.JWSAlgorithm.RS256)
                .build();
        JWKSet jwkSet = new JWKSet(rsaKey);
        return new ImmutableJWKSet<>(jwkSet);
    }

    private static KeyPair generateRsaKey() {
        KeyPair keyPair;
        try {
            KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
            keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
            keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
        }
        return keyPair;
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder(JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource) {
        return OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.jwtDecoder(jwkSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthorizationServerSettings authorizationServerSettings() {
        return AuthorizationServerSettings.builder()
                .multipleIssuersAllowed(true)
                .build();
    }


    @Bean
    public OAuth2TokenCustomizer<JwtEncodingContext> idTokenCustomizer() {
        return new FederatedIdentityIdTokenCustomizer();
    }


    @Bean
    OAuth2AuthorizationService jdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService(
            JdbcOperations jdbcOperations,
            RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository) {
        return new JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService(jdbcOperations, registeredClientRepository);
    }

    @Bean
    OAuth2AuthorizationConsentService jdbcOAuth2AuthorizationConsentService(
            JdbcOperations jdbcOperations,
            RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository) {
        return new JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationConsentService(jdbcOperations, registeredClientRepository);
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
        return new SessionRegistryImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpSessionEventPublisher httpSessionEventPublisher() {
        return new HttpSessionEventPublisher();
    }

    private LogoutSuccessHandler oidcLogoutSuccessHandler(ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository) {
        OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler oidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler = new OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler(clientRegistrationRepository);
        oidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler.setPostLogoutRedirectUri("/oauth2/authorization/keycloak");
        return oidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler;
    }
}

the client registration bean:
    @Bean
    public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        RegisteredClient exampleClient = RegisteredClient.withId("2bee2e72-af4t-43ad-tb2q-0b11501b4a15")
                .clientId("example-client")
                .clientSecret("{noop}password")
                .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_POST)
                .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN)
                .redirectUri("http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/keycloak")
                .redirectUri("https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/callback")
                .scope(OidcScopes.OPENID)
                .scope(OidcScopes.PROFILE).scope(OidcScopes.EMAIL)
                .tokenSettings(TokenSettings.builder().accessTokenTimeToLive(Duration.ofDays(10))
                        .refreshTokenTimeToLive(Duration.ofDays(8)).reuseRefreshTokens(false)
                        .accessTokenFormat(OAuth2TokenFormat.SELF_CONTAINED)
                        .x509CertificateBoundAccessTokens(true)
                        .build()).build();

        JdbcRegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository =
                new JdbcRegisteredClientRepository(jdbcTemplate);
        registeredClientRepository.save(exampleClient);

        return registeredClientRepository;
    }

id token and access customization:
public final class FederatedIdentityIdTokenCustomizer implements OAuth2TokenCustomizer<JwtEncodingContext> {

    private static final Set<String> ID_TOKEN_CLAIMS = Collections.unmodifiableSet(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(
            IdTokenClaimNames.ISS,
            IdTokenClaimNames.SUB,
            IdTokenClaimNames.AUD,
            IdTokenClaimNames.EXP,
            IdTokenClaimNames.IAT,
            IdTokenClaimNames.AUTH_TIME,
            IdTokenClaimNames.NONCE,
            IdTokenClaimNames.ACR,
            IdTokenClaimNames.AMR,
            IdTokenClaimNames.AZP,
            IdTokenClaimNames.AT_HASH,
            IdTokenClaimNames.C_HASH
    )));

    @Override
    public void customize(JwtEncodingContext context) {
        if (OidcParameterNames.ID_TOKEN.equals(context.getTokenType().getValue())) {
            Map<String, Object> thirdPartyClaims = extractClaims(context.getPrincipal());
            context.getClaims().claims(existingClaims -> {
                // Remove conflicting claims set by this authorization server
                existingClaims.keySet().forEach(thirdPartyClaims::remove);

                // Remove standard id_token claims that could cause problems with clients
                ID_TOKEN_CLAIMS.forEach(thirdPartyClaims::remove);

                // Add all other claims directly to id_token
                existingClaims.putAll(thirdPartyClaims);
            });
        }

        if (OAuth2TokenType.ACCESS_TOKEN.equals(context.getTokenType())) {
            Authentication principal = context.getPrincipal();

            if (principal.getPrincipal() instanceof OAuth2User) {
                OAuth2User oauth2User = (OAuth2User) principal.getPrincipal();
                Map<String, Object> attributes = oauth2User.getAttributes();

                context.getClaims().claim("email", attributes.get("email"));
                context.getClaims().claim("name", attributes.get("name"));
                context.getClaims().claim("email_verified", attributes.get("email_verified"));
                context.getClaims().claim("family_name", attributes.get("family_name"));
            }
        }
    }

    private Map<String, Object> extractClaims(Authentication principal) {
        Map<String, Object> claims;
        if (principal.getPrincipal() instanceof OidcUser) {
            OidcUser oidcUser = (OidcUser) principal.getPrincipal();
            OidcIdToken idToken = oidcUser.getIdToken();
            claims = idToken.getClaims();
        } else if (principal.getPrincipal() instanceof OAuth2User) {
            OAuth2User oauth2User = (OAuth2User) principal.getPrincipal();
            claims = oauth2User.getAttributes();
        } else {
            claims = Collections.emptyMap();
        }

        return new HashMap<>(claims);
    }
}


My Attempts and Expectations
I think the issue might be that the session isn’t being saved, since SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication(); returns null. I’m using JDBC to store the session, but it still doesn’t delete the session, and the user isn’t logged out.
I’m sorry for the long message, and I really appreciate any help you can provide!

Does the client store JWTs in any way (e.g. in localStorage)?

yes, frontend use cookies

Which cookies are you storing the JWTs in? Did you try including these cookies in the .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID") call instead of just deleting JSESSIONID on logout?

@dan1st I’m not understand the first part of your question. I don’t handle the front-end—it just calls the logout endpoint with the id_token_hint in the query. I also tried deleting the JSESSIONID. Do you have an example of including cookies in the .deleteCookies method?

When the user is loggoed out, the client is logged out, you should ensure revoking of any tokens as mentioned in Anjali Khurana's answer. You should also ideally make sure that the clients clears any tokens it stores. If these tokens are stored as cookies, you could use .deleteCookies(names, of, the, cookies, here) - but you should still make sure everything is revoked properly.

Have a look at https://chatgpt.com/c/66ef0d42-ae54-8001-b397-5cca2a9e330c

1st, I'm not sure to understand why you are using Spring Authorization Server instead of using Keycloak directly as an OpenID Provider for the rest of your system. 2nd, unless the OAuth2 client part of your React app runs on the server (with the NextAuth lib or alike), it can't be confidential (a secret manipulated by Javascript code running on user devices is anything but secret). 3rd, tokens should not leave your server. See the OAuth2 BFF pattern for that.

Hello @ch4mp . For your 1st point, I'm using Spring Authorization Server for custom session management purpose. I plan to implement a custom auth server to customize everything as needed, but I want to use a third party for the authentication process.
Could you explain your 2nd and 3rd points in more detail? Also, what does it mean that a React app can't be confidential? thanks a lot

Javascript code running in a browser can't hold a secret actually secret and confidential OAuth2 clients are expected not to make their secret public. About issues with sending tokens to the user agent, it is exposed in this article and detailed by Spring Security team members in the ticket linked in the intro.

When the user logs out, you may need to invalidate the session in the client application (or the Authorization Server) by calling:
request.getSession().invalidate();

This ensures that the session data is removed and the user is fully logged out. For Spring Security, you can also use:
SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();

This removes the authentication information from the SecurityContext as well.

Ensure that tokens are properly invalidated or revoked during the logout process by using the OAuth2AuthorizationService to remove or revoke access tokens, refresh tokens, and other OAuth2 authorization information.

Thanks for your response, can you explain your answer a bit more? I’m not customizing the logout endpoint, so I’m not sure how to handling OAuth2AuthorizationService.

I don't know whether this is applicable at all since you are using Spring Resource Server but Spring Security: How to revoke a refresh token on log-out? seems to be about revocation with Spring OAuth2 client

Hello @dan1st. I think I'll need to customize the Spring Authorization Server logout endpoints. I'll try to use it for my situation. Thanks a lot

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
